# Oracle Trigger changing a value

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

say you have a table that has {Name, value}
Can you create a Trigger that if a new row is inserted with the name 'Bob', increase the value associated to Bob by 25%?
If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE_NAME
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
   IF :new.NAME = 'Bob' then
      :new.VALUE := :new.VALUE + (:new.VALUE*0.25) ;
  END IF; 
END; 
/
```

I'm not oracle expert but I tried. Hope u can have solution.

Comment: Beware before triggers can be fired more than once for a single statement execution. It's better to store necessary information in some PL/SQL package and then modify the value in AFTER trigger.

Comment: @Ivan. Thanks for ur suggetion. Actually I havent worked on oracle beofre. I just tried above thing by googling. So it'll be better you guide how to implement it